# Escaping Java variables to serialise SQL statement to string

Tags: java, sqlite, ignite, database-backups, change-data-capture

We have an event system producing database events for change data capture.

The system sends an event which contains the INSERT or UPDATE statement with `?` placeholders and an array of the ordered values matching each question mark.

I want to use this for per hour backup files so if I get a statement like:

`insert into T0(a,b,c) VALUES(?,?,?)`

with an array of values `1`, `2` and `it's his` then I write the a line to the backup file for that hour as

`insert into T0(a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,'it\'s his');`

A few things:

1. Is it only strings that need escaping? We don't have or allow binary columns
2. Is there a Java library that can do this already (from the Spring eco-system, Apache or otherwise)?
3. I've seen the Postgres JDBC code for escaping https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/Utils.java - is that sufficient?

I was also thinking of creating a SQLite database for each hour, writing to SQLite and then dumping it to the `hr.sql` text file. This has the advantage of capitalising on all the hardwork and thought already put into SQLite handling escaping but feels like overkill if there's a way to do the toString in Java then append a line to the file.

There's a performance consideration in using SQLite as well furthering my hesitation to that that route.

Comment: JDBC already handles the escaping. Check out [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: I don't want to execute the prepared statement though, I want to serialise it to string. Did I miss an API on the prepared statement class to do this? As far as I know you'd normally call `executeUpdate` or something similar...that's not what I want. The query is already being sent to the database which will handle it. This is a backup solution outside the DB...since it doesn't have one that supports what we want to do with backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some options.

Postgres JDBC driver is this https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/core/Utils.java and other impl. is even more simple https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy/blob/master/src/main/java/com/p6spy/engine/common/Value.java#L172 literally doing

```java
ESPECIAL_CHARACTER_PATTERN.matcher(stringValue).replaceAll("''")
```

Where `private static final Pattern ESPECIAL_CHARACTER_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("'");`

In both cases, only strings need this as I thought and binary is handled separately but we don't have/need binary.

Digging further I rediscovered ESAPI https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy
They have a lib for escaping SQL https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-4-escaping-all-user-supplied-input

https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/MySQLCodec.java